# asp.net after building in visual studio 2015, IIS takes time to respond around 6 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been searching the net about this problem for a long time. I'm building asp.net application. After changing the codes, building the app is very fast less than 1 second or 1. But then when I click on the page of the site in my local machine to see the changes, the page takes around 5~7 seconds. However, succeeding requests are instant.

My pc is running on i7, ssd harddisk and 16Gig ram. I don't think its my pc.

Is this normal? Any suggestions please. Below is the screenshot. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Is it taking same/more time to load on subsequent requests to same page? Also did you deployed application to IIS or running from Visual Studio?

Comment: @Siva Gopal subsequent request on same page is instant. I deployed in from visual studio